# Loop FOR de tupla dentro outra tupla

Tags: python

Estou tentando rodar um loop de tuplas dentro de outra tupla. Quando rodo o aplicativo ele só me retorna a última tupla.

```
minha_tupla = (('willian','123','25.26'),('carla','654','45.58'))

titulos = ('nome','cod','valor')
meu_dic = {}

for x in range(0,len(minha_tupla)):
    for t in range(0,len(titulos)):
        meu_dic[titulos[t]] = minha_tupla[x][t]

print(meu_dic)
```

Comment: Seu problema é com o laço `for` e a referência. Você não está criando um novo registro a cada iteração, mas somente alterando os itens. Em outras palavras você passa os valores da primeira tupla no 1º laço do `for` e depois sobrescreveos mesmos valores com os dados passados pelo segundo `for`. Sugiro criar uma lista de dicionários.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que o dicionário é sobrescrito a cada iteração. Na primeira iteração, por exemplo, você seta o nome para "willian", e na segunda iteração o nome é setado para "carla", sobrescrevendo o valor anterior.

Se você quer que cada registro corresponda a um dicionário, então você deve criar um novo a cada iteração, e guardá-los em uma outra estrutura, como por exemplo uma lista:

```
minha_tupla = (('willian','123','25.26'),('carla','654','45.58'))
titulos = ('nome','cod','valor')
valores = [] # lista que irá ter os dicionários 
for dados in minha_tupla:
    valores.append(dict(zip(titulos, dados))) # adicionar novo dicionário
 
print(valores)
```

Repare que não precisa de `range` para iterar, você pode usar `for elemento in tupla` para já ter o próprio elemento.

E também não precisa criar as chaves uma a uma. Basta usar [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), que percorre simultaneamente os títulos e os respectivos valores, assim o dicionário já é criado corretamente.

O resultado é uma lista de dicionários, sendo que cada dicionário corresponde a uma das tuplas originais:

```
[{'nome': 'willian', 'cod': '123', 'valor': '25.26'},
 {'nome': 'carla', 'cod': '654', 'valor': '45.58'}]
```

---

E se quiser, pode trocar o `for` acima por uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
valores = [ dict(zip(titulos, dados)) for dados in minha_tupla ]
```

Comment: Brother, é isso mesmo... poxa cara, muito obrigado. Show de bola. Obrigado.